# Cannot parse dst/src address

Tags: openvpn, grep

I created second ubuntu and then I installed openvpn then I wrote that command:

```
sudo ss -tupln ׀ grep openvpn
```

But was written

```
Error: an inet prefix is expected rather than "׀".
Cannot parse dst/src address.
```

What must I do?

Comment: What is ׀? Doesn't seem to be the pipe character `|`? Googling says something about Hebrew punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

You should stop copying code blocks from untrusted bad-formatted blogs.

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to enter pipe character `|` to get the command below:

```
sudo ss -tupln | grep openvpn
```

---

Technically the `׀` and `|` are absolutely different symbols:

```
$ printf "׀" | hexdump
0000000 80d7                                   
0000002

$ printf "|" | hexdump
0000000 007c                                   
0000001
```

Comment: I did it , but when I write ip add, I face one problem : 3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none